# Third Eye and how the brain would see the world

Tags: optics, vision, perception

Let's suppose that through engineering, a third bionic eye would be attached to a human and interfaced directly with the brain. Let's assume this third eye is positioned in the middle of the forehead.

If all three eyes are being utilized by the brain and their images merged, would this give us a better depth vision?

Comment: Given that [Structure from Motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_from_Motion) algorithms do benefit from larger number of photos, I'd suppose the brain aided with a third eye that's not located between two original eyes would also get somewhat fuller 3D image.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't a Physics question.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the ideal stackexchange site to place it. If you could elucidate me please, I'd be grateful.

Comment: There is an interesting physics question hiding in here about how parallax and depth perception are related, but the hypothetical brain/forehead implant is a huge distraction. It did, however, remind me about the fellow with vertically-aligned eyes in [this brief public service announcement](https://youtu.be/dechvhb0Meo).

Answer (score 2):

I'm gonna assume it is placed in a socket kind of structure bored into the forehead. I seriously doubt any improvement to FOV, since it's vision is also bordered by a socket, like the other eyes.

Although 2 eyes are all the brain needs to perceive depth, a third  eye may improve depth perception at certain angles. If both your eyes are looking to the right, for example, the parallax would be pretty small, since your right eye is almost "in front of" your left eye. The third eye would be a big plus in this situation.